# Using robots.txt to block sessionID URLs

Tags: url, web-crawlers, robots.txt, url-parameters

I've got a problem with Googlebot literally crawling millions of URLs that are the same, because ";jsessionid" keeps getting inserted into the URL (something I cannot change due to the work environment).

An example URL is:

```
catalog/product-category/product/;jsessionid=Mf87s+Xw2P8ByQYz2CyQjEJh.prod-14?f=p%3A100-200
```

Can I update my robots.txt to say:

```
Disallow: /;jsessionid=*
```

Does anyone see an issue with doing that? I can also canonicalize the pages, but I feel that using robots is a better solution so Googlebot won't have to waste any resources crawling the URLs in the first place.

Comment: Are you linking to the non-jsessionid URLs? What happens when you naviagate to the non-jsessionid URLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should exclude such urls from crawling, because you spend your whole crawling budget for those useless urls. Read [this](https://goo.gl/UnSi8e) topic at Google Product Forum.

set the robots rule like:

```
disallow: /*jsessionid*
```

Comment: Should I set the rule like yours, or /*/;jsessionid* ?

Comment: @czmudzin i would say, use it like in my example

Answer (score 2):

```
Disallow: /*;jsessionid
```

A more precise syntax for what you want. A trailing `*` does nothing.

Comment: Do you have documentation to support this?  I know that non-wildcard rules in robots.txt are "starts with" rules and that a wildcard at the end is redundant.   But once a rule has a wildcard, I wouldn't necessarily expect it to be interpreted as a "starts with" rule.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You can check the examples on [google's robots.txt page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_txt).  One of the examples is that `/*.php` matches `/folder/filename.php?parameters`.

Comment: it's remembering me to [MrWhite's answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87594/how-do-i-disallow-variable-parent-directories-and-subdirectory-with-robots-txt) to my question

Comment: Greate answer! "Disallow: /*;jsessionid" includes "Disallow: /*/;jsessionid" and "Disallow: /*jsessionid*". Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

Based on [official guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls#best-practices), don't use the robots.txt file for canonicalization purposes.

You can blocks sessionid URLs using [Parameter Handling](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1235687)

If you block using robots.txt, you may lose the search ranking signal from the link to your URL with sessionid/params.