# How do I disallow variable parent directories and subdirectory with robots.txt?

Tags: seo, search-engines, robots.txt

I want to disallow robots to index some pages of my site. For example, I want to disallow the following pages:

```
/category/name1/page/1
/category/name1/page/2
/category/etc/page/3
```

But I want to allow these pages:

```
/category/name1/
/category/name1/
/category/etc/
```

How do I express this in `robots.txt`?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /category/*/page/*
```

Is that right or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disallow *crawling* of the URLs ending in `page/` then yes, you can use a wildcard like you mentioned. However, there is no need to use a wildcard at the end of the pattern, since `robots.txt` is *prefixing matching* by default.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /category/*/page/
```

That will still *allow* the crawling of the less specific URLs mentioned.

Note that the wildcard `*` is an extension of the "standard". Whilst all the main search engine bots support it, not all (good) bots do.

Comment: Can't i use wildcard? Because I have thousands pages and category names so  i must write each page?

Comment: Sorry, yes you can use a wildcard - just realised the significance of the wildcard in your question! I've updated my answer.